# Running 3 Android Emulators -- failure

Tags: android, android-emulator, virtual-device-manager

I am building/testing a group chat and events application, and need to be able to test on 3+ devices.

Using Android Virtual Device manager, I can successfully run two emulators, yet starting a third, simply displays the `android` naming and loading, never getting to the home screen.

I do have 16 GB ram, and never reach above 14 GB with all processes running...

What configuration do I have to change to allow for running 3 emulators?

Comment: Are you using windows or linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try HAXM accelerator. from SDK update window, download intel x86 accelerated device image (HAXM)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the Gennymotion emulator, & set 1GB ram for each device. Be sure not to choose a fancy device like nexus 5.

Comment: I had first attempted using genymotion but it kept crashing, throwing errors about OVA files that never went away, the same problems other people have had